# read children from dynamically filled stackpanel

Tags: c#, xaml

so I am dynamically populating a nested stack panel with fields for data entry, in the inner `StackPanel` is a Class that inherits `StackPanel` but contains datatype and other metadata, I add a text block for a label and a second field that is dynamically generated and may be a `TextBox`, a `ComboBox`, a `CheckBox` or others. once entry is done I need to capture the data and move it to a class for processing. How can I get Data out of the inner `StackPannel`? I tried `foreach x in children` but that throws an error for each object of a different type. To simplify I only show code for `TextBox` and `CheckBox`

```
private void _LoadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<IEnteredData> enteredData= new List<IEnteredData>();
        enteredData= _ExtractEnteredData(FirsColumn, enteredData);
        enteredData= _ExtractEnteredData(SecondColumn, enteredData);
        foo(enteredData);
    }

    private List<IEnteredData> _ExtractEnteredData(StackPanel thisColumn, List<IEnteredData> enteredData)
    {
        foreach (StackPanelBatchInput entry in thisColumn.Children)
        {
            string enteredValue= null;
            foreach (TextBox textinput in entry.Children)
                enteredValue = textinput.Text;
            foreach (CheckBox checkBox in entry.Children)
            {
                if (checkBox.IsChecked  == true)
                    enteredValue = "true";
                else
                    enteredValue = "false";
            }

            if (enteredValue != null)
                enteredData.Add(AssignValueType(entry, enteredValue));
        }

        return enteredData;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, when the code get into the foreach loop he take out the first child of the *StackPanel* and cast them to *StackPanelBatchInput* for example. But when the child object is not a type of *StackPanelBatchInput* you will get an exception.

Try this one for the foreach loops:

```
foreach (StackPanelBatchInput entry in thisColumn.Children.OfType<StackPanelBatchInput>())
{
     ...
     foreach (TextBox textinput in entry.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
        enteredValue = textinput.Text;
     ...
}
```

This will filter elements of a specified type (for exaple TextBox, CheckBox, ...). For more information to
[OfType<>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1)

If this not fix your problem, can you may post your XAML-Code and the exception please. This will be more helpfull for the reader.